# Run microsoft/nanoserver in a docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nano-server

[Link to microsoft/nanoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/nanoserver/iis/)

If I follow the process in the link above I can get docker nano-server to run inside of docker on the command line..

> RUN --name nanoiis -d -it -p 8080:80 nanoserver/iis

is the commend line is use.

I want to put this into a docker file and build and image.  So here is my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver

# Set the working directory to /app 

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Public directory contents into the container at /app 

ADD ./Public /app

# -p 8080:80 Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host. 

RUN --name nanoiis -d -it -p 8080:80 nanoserver/iis
```

I get an error

> Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 12: Unknown
>   flag: name

**My question is what am I doing wrong?**

I am following the example on building a docker image here:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

**Next question is what is the command I would use to get my app running?  In the example they use.**

> CMD ["python", "app.py"]
>    What should I use to get nano-server running?

**Last point me to some documentation to get a web site running into the Nano-Server.  It seems that Nano-Server has changed it role within Microsoft.**